# Generic return for function

Tags: apex, apex-sharing

I have the following function that creates a share to a custom object:

```
public static Order_Request__Share generateOrderRequestShare(Id orderRequestID, Id userId, Boolean readOnly){
    System.debug('generateOrderRequestShare');
    Order_Request__Share shareTmp = new Order_Request__Share();
    if (!readOnly){
        shareTmp.AccessLevel = 'Edit';
    } else {
        shareTmp.AccessLevel = 'Read';
    }
    shareTmp.ParentId = orderRequestID;
    shareTmp.RowCause = 'Manual';
    shareTmp.UserOrGroupId = userId; 
    return shareTmp;
}
```

i want to do the same function, but for the object "SBQQ__Quote__Share", but i don't want to have the exact same function again. like this:

```
public static Order_Request__Share generateOrderRequestShare(Id orderRequestID, Id userId, Boolean readOnly){
    System.debug('generateOrderRequestShare');
    Order_Request__Share shareTmp = new Order_Request__Share();
    if (!readOnly){
        shareTmp.AccessLevel = 'Edit';
    } else {
        shareTmp.AccessLevel = 'Read';
    }
    shareTmp.ParentId = orderRequestID;
    shareTmp.RowCause = 'Manual';
    shareTmp.UserOrGroupId = userId; 
    return shareTmp;
}

public static SBQQ__Quote__Share generateQuoteShare(Id quoteId, Id userId, Boolean readOnly){
    SBQQ__Quote__Share shareTmp = new SBQQ__Quote__Share();
    if (!readOnly){
        shareTmp.AccessLevel = 'Edit';
    } else {
        shareTmp.AccessLevel = 'Read';
    }
    shareTmp.ParentId = quoteId;
    shareTmp.RowCause = 'Manual';
    shareTmp.UserOrGroupId = userId; 
    return shareTmp;
}
```

Is there a way i can create a generic function that will return a different object every time?

Comment: You can do it dynamically with `getDescribe` apex. Here is a sample code. Replace Account with your object. In the newAccount instance, you just need to do  `newObject.put('AccessLevel', 'Edit');`
`Schema.SObjectType objectType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Order_Request__Share');`
`SObject newObject = objectType.newSObject();`

Comment: @Kevan Comments really are not intended for answers; it would have been better to just add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the generic sObject type and the sobjecType classes, you can accomplish your goals. Here's an example:

```
public static sObject createShare(sObjectType shareType, Id parentId, Id userOrGroupId, Boolean readOnly) {
  sObject result = shareType.newSobject();
  result.put('AccessLevel', readOnly? 'Read': 'Edit');
  result.put('ParentId', parentId);
  result.put('UserOrGroupId', userOrGroupId);
  result.put('RowCause','Manual');
  return result;
}
```

Your method would be called slightly differently:

```
sObject shareRecord = createShare(SBQQ__Quote__Share.SobjectType, record.Id, someUser.Id, true);
```